# How to work with meteor, git and different dev platforms?

Tags: git, meteor, gitignore

I am on Windows; another developper is on linux.
My release and versions files are not the same as his.

With Git, how can we do development on the same project but on different platforms? What is the strategy? Do we keep local versions of "release" and "versions" and ignore the two files in Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could both use the same version. Like if developer A is using v1 and you're using v0.9, then your app has to ultimately support v0.9 because any new apis beyond this won't work in your development environment.

The way I work is to commit everything to git. And so any developer working on that project can ue the desired Meteor version. So if my release file says its using Meteor@v1 then all developers will be using that version when they run the `meteor` command in the CLI.

--UPDATE--
Since you can't use the same version, then git ignore the release file and use separate release files for each of our development environments.

Comment: _Well you could both use the same version_can you use the last Metor version on Windows ? _So if my release file says its using Meteor@v1 then all developers will be using that version when they run the meteor command in the CLI._ We are not on same OS, we can not use the same version